# Partition of an $n$-element set such that the smallest component has at least $k$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

We know that the number of $s$-partition of an $n$-element set is given by the Stirling number of the second kind. However, is there any result on the number of $s$-partition such that every component has at least $k$ elements, where $k$ is any integer?

In particular, it would be great if we can get some value such that the number that we are seeking is of the same order, or equivalently, find some upper and lower bound as a function of $n,s,k$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One can write down its exponential generating function: it's the coefficient of $x^n/n!$ in
$$\frac1{s!}\left(\sum_{r=k}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!}\right)^s.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I just verified it, and it makes perfect sense. However, I am looking for some closed-form expression or at least some inequality that bounds the value from above or below tightly (up to constant factor, let's say). Are you aware of any such result?